# Update a global variable every 180 seconds without sleeping or blocking the client

Tags: go, networking, time, global-variables

I'm a writing a peer in a P2P protocol. I have a global variable representing a map of the peers I want to communicate with. However, I want to update this map every 180 seconds without sleeping or blocking the client because I still need to be able to send packets and process the ones incoming.

The structure of the client so far ressembles to something like this:

```
var map[int]Peer
func main() {
    for {
        // Every 180 seconds, update peers map
        // send packets / receive packets
    }
}
```

The problematic part is the timed update. I've made searches and a lot of the possible solutions uses `time.AfterFunc` or a `Sleep`. But I'm unsure about the behaviour of `AfterFunc` considering it's a Goroutine and as far as I understand, only a copy of the global variables are passed to the Goroutines right? So it may not a viable solution, or maybe I misunderstood the underlying concepts.

I think there might a very simple solution I'm not able to come up with. I'd be glad to read some possible solutions to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is passed to goroutines. Global variables (more precisely package level variables) exist in one instance. Without passing them, there are no multiple copies of them. If accessed from multiple goroutines (where at least one of the accesses is a write) must be synchronized. All accesses (even only reads)!

Comment: @icza Oh I see, thanks. So basically I would put my map in a `struct` with a mutex, use a goroutine to update it every 180 seconds, and in the main `for loop` I would check the mutex before iterating through the peers, right?

Comment: The `struct` you speak of plays no role here. Just make sure to lock / unlock the mutex when you access the shared variable.

Answer (score 1):

> only a copy of the global variables are passed to the Goroutines right?

No, a goroutine **can** mutate a global variable. But if you do it this way, pay extra attention to data races. You might want to add a mutex to protect concurrent access of the global variable.